# SQL Server Compact ADO.NET Data Provider Error Message: There was an error parsing the query

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

The query give an error message. while updating Colman length is **4000 character**. still give an error.

```
 UPDATE Finalresult
SET solveAnswer = '$C Rajgopalachari$Mohd. Fazal$M Pallam Raju$R Chandrashekhar$Kirti Prasad$Kirti Prasad$A fall in income of people$Fall in production due to fall in demand leading to fall in jobs$I don t know$ONGC$2018 Rs per month$Corporate Social Responsibilities$Operations plan$None OF the above$Nokia$Melinda Gates$Indira Sharma$Christina Tan$Shantanu Narayen$Rajiv Jain' where section_name=' PEST Test '
```

error message is.

[image]

Comment: it looks like you have single quotes in your string that are not escaped.

Comment: ok get rid of `TABLE` in your query. It is not correct syntax.
 `UPDATE [tablename] SET` aka `UPDATE Finalresult` ...

Comment: @ serakfalcon: Still give an error.

Comment: ok can you post the table structure and name please